# React Formik :Custom onBlur unable to access useField meta

Tags: reactjs, formik

I'm trying to access the meta from `const [field, meta, helpers] = useField` from a custom `onBlur` handler. Similar to such:

```
const [field, meta, helpers] = useField<string>(useFieldProps);

const handleBlur = (event) => {
  field.onBlur(event);
  console.log('meta.error is: ', meta.error);
};

return (
  <input
    {...field}
    onBlur={handleBlur}
  />
);
```

I would have assumed the fact I called `field.onBlur(event);` as to not overwrite Formiks default onBlur, state would have been updated and I could see the error from `meta.error`?

However, it returns `undefined`. It returns the error value if I cause another `onBlur` event and the field remains invalid. Basically, after am  `onBlur`, state seems to be behind, even when calling `field.onBlur(event);`.

Is what I'm trying to achieve possible or is there another way to do this? Thanks